# Boost Asio serial connection doesn't send correctly after a restart

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I found one thread that seems to have exactly the same problem here, however, this thread never got a reply after the OP updated it with his correction:

[Boost asio serial port initially sending bad data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997499/boost-asio-serial-port-initially-sending-bad-data)

Basically, when I attempt to connect to a serial device with my program after a computer restart, boost::asio writes don't seem to send the right data. But if I use a different program to open the port and send some data, then run my program, it will send everything correctly.

I'm running on VS 2015 in Windows.

Here's my code (I simplified the amount of data sent in send for this example, so ignore the extra steps):

```
 boost::asio::io_service io;
 boost::asio::serial_port serial;

 Serial::Serial(char * port, unsigned int baud): io(), serial(io, port)
 {
     serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud));
 }

 void Serial::send(int cmd)
 {
     int cmU[] = {cmd};
     boost::asio::write(serial, boost::asio::buffer(cmU, 1));
 }

 void Serial::doStuff()
 {
     send(123);
 }
```

I've experimented with adding this line in the constructor as well:

```
 PurgeComm(serial.lowest_layer().native_handle(), PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
```

Still no joy there though.

What am I missing?

Comment: Some error checking would be nice: that the port opened OK and that the write wrote the requested number of bytes.  Note you only requested 1 byte to be transmitted, yet it looks like you expected to send an integer.

Comment: @ravenspoint Yeah, it's technically an integer, but we only send values up to 254 so we can safely trim everything after the first byte. I'll check for errors ASAP - although it's weird to me that it only doesn't work if it's the first program to access the port after a computer restart.

Comment: Your posted code attempts to send integer value 1234

Comment: @ravenspoint Ah you're right, error on my part when I put in a random value for the doStuff. Fixed!